# How do I see the passing tests with Mocha?

Tags: testing, mocha.js

I come from a RoR background, and with rspec testing, if you want to see the passed tests all you have to do is run the test as:

rspec --format documentation

Is there an equivalent for running Mocha tests with Node?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`mocha -R spec` will show you each test run and whether it passes or not.